# 400 Error Using file_get_contents on public endpoint

Tags: php, rest, endpoint

I'm trying to access this endpoint of the Coinbase API:

https://api.pro.coinbase.com/currencies

Notice the endpoint is public/unauthenticated, and the [API documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-currencies) confirms that

```
$coinbase_coins = file_get_contents('https://api.pro.coinbase.com/currencies');
$coinbase_coins = json_decode($coinbase_coins, true);
```

The above code throws a 400 error. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I can access the endpoint just fine in the browser. I can access other public endpoints in different APIs, so I dont think it's a problem on the server.

I've also tried cURL with no luck.

Can someone show a working example in PHP by chance? Thanks!

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: Yea, I am on a windows machine

Comment: PHP manual for `file_get_contents()` says windows can be buggy when dealing with SSL.  It also says that PHP is capable of detecting this issue when you use the http://  prefix, which you did. Maybe there is still some issue with that.  Just a thought.

Comment: @Joseph_J that notice is for connecting to IIS servers running on Windows, nothing to do with the client. It's also a very old notice.

Comment: I can confirm same 400 response trying to get this file. It's a server-side thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a server-side issue; it's blocking requests without a browser UA. You can set one and it seems to work fine.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(["http"=>["user_agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"]]);
$coinbase_coins = file_get_contents('https://api.pro.coinbase.com/currencies', true, $ctx);
$coinbase_coins = json_decode($coinbase_coins, true);

print_r($coinbase_coins);
```